# Activity Monitor does not have the "Kind" column

Tags: activity-monitor, processor, universal-binaries

Activity Monitor doesn't show the "Kind" column, and does not give me the option to enable it. It's not in the list of columns I can enable.

My friend's M1 Mac has the Kind column in the list of columns he can enable. It's between Real Shared Memory and Sudden Termination. It's not there for mine. The light-colored screenshot is my Mac. The dark-colored screenshot is my friend's. You can see the Kind column is highlighted on his, and missing on mine.

I've tried [deleting Activity Monitor preferences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380385/activity-monitor-columns-missing) to no avail, and of course I've resized the window and made sure it's not already showing off the edge of the window. It's like the column never existed.

[image: My available columns]
[image: My friend's available columns]

Comment: What model / os version are both your and your friends Mac?

Comment: @bmike Mine is a 16" Intel MacBook Pro from 2019. My friend is on an M1 MacBook Pro.

Comment: I will also say I have a totally unproven guess, which is that if my machine is literally incapable of running anything from any other architecture, they don't allow the Kind column to be shown. But if it was able, it would allow the Kind column. That's my guess.

Comment: May have to dust off the old PPC to intel days and [refresh](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/428037/5472) myself on [universal binaries](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/404325/5472) with recent Xcode.